# Java - Generic abstract class for Enum Converter

Tags: java, enums, abstract-class, generic-programming

I have some enums which are name("String") and value("Integer") pair, current in each enum I have to implement a @JsonCreator method for Json Deserialize which the input could be either name or value

```
//User Enum
public enum UserType {
   StakeHolder(1),...

   private static final Map<String, UserType> helper = ImmutableMap.<String, UserType>builder()
            .put(String.valueOf(StakeHolder.getValue()), StakeHolder)
            .put(StakeHolder.name(), StakeHolder)
            .build();

   @JsonCreator
   public static UserType jsonDeserialize(String json) {
        return helper.get(json);
   }
}

//Role Enum
public enum RoleType {
   Admin(1),...

   private static final Map<String, RoleType> helper = ImmutableMap.<String, RoleType>builder()
            .put(String.valueOf(Admin.getValue()), Admin)
            .put(Admin.name(), Admin)
            .build();

   @JsonCreator
   public static RoleType jsonDeserialize(String json) {
        return helper.get(json);
   }
}
```

but I was wondering if there is any way to create an abstract class that can have the implementation overall enums, that's to avoid similar "duplicate" code implemented in each of my enum always. Current code would be like

```
public abstract class JsonDeserializeEnum<E extends Enum<E>> {
  // protected Enum<E> myEnums;
  // private static final Map<String, E> myEnumHelper; ???

  public JsonDeserializeEnum() {
    super();
    // how to loop through myEnums to do something like
    // for(E iterator : myEnums.value()) not work...myEnums is not a collection of enums?
    // myEnumHelper.put(String.valueOf(iterator.getValue()), (E) iterator);
    // myEnumHelper.put(iterator.name, (E) iterator);
  } 

  @JsonCreator
   public static E jsonDeserialize(String json) {
        return myEnumHelper.get(json);
   }
}

//then
public enum UserType implements JsonDeserializeEnum<UserType>{
    StakeHolder(1),...
}
public enum RoleType implements JsonDeserializeEnum<RoleType>{
    Admin(1),...
}
```

I am stuck at two challenges here,

1) I would like to have an init/constructor in my abstract class that can load all available Enums into a static Map(only once), for example,

when calling `UserType`, load all user type enum into the static map, then deserialize from that map; when calling `RoleType`, load all role type enum into map, then deserialize from same map

2) If No.1 is not possible, it's Ok, Let's say if I will get rid of the map in my abstract class, but still use map defined in each of my Enum, is there anyway that my abstract class know and can use the map defined in my Enum?

Comment: Beside the key clash in your proposed implementation, the main problem is that `jsonDeserialize()` **has to** be `static`. That means you'll necessarily have to declare it on each enum. You can choose to externalize the lookup logic (such as by changing your map to a map of maps with an entry by enum type in your interface), but that will ameliorate very little.

Comment: Gotcha! Let's say if I will get rid of the map in my abstract class, but still use map defined in each of my Enum, is there anyway that my abstract class know and can use the map defined in my Enum?

Comment: First of all, you can't make your enums *extend* an abstract class. You can make them *implement* an interface. And yes, you can define a contract that makes your enums implement a method that returns the local map, **but it will have to be an instance method**. When you look at such an implementation in retrospect, you'll probably find that your current version is the more preferable of two ugly designs (my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use a `JsonDeserializer`. First you need to use an interface to be able to use the same code for all your enums:

```
public interface ValueEnum {
    String name();
    int value();
}
```

And implement it in every of the enums

```
public enum EnumExample implements ValueEnum {

    Hello(1),
    World(2);

    public final int value;

    private EnumExample(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

(The `name()` is already implemented by the Enum)

Then you can move your map creation to a separate class (I use the java HashMap, you can use whatever you like)

```
public class ValueEnumDeserializer<T extends ValueEnum> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private final HashMap<String, T> map;

    public ValueEnumDeserializer(Class<T> c) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        for (final T i : c.getEnumConstants()) {
            map.put(i.name(), i);
            map.put(String.valueOf(i.value()), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return map.get(p.getText());
    }
}
```

And then when you create your object mapper you must pass the deserializer

```
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(EnumExample1.class, new ValueEnumDeserializer<>(EnumExample1.class));
    module.addDeserializer(EnumExample2.class, new ValueEnumDeserializer<>(EnumExample2.class));
    module.addDeserializer(EnumExample3.class, new ValueEnumDeserializer<>(EnumExample3.class));
    mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thank you! A couple of questions that I am not quite understanding
1) The "map" in "ValueEnumDeserializer", would it be initialized every time when deserialize a json request since it's in the constructor of the class but not static?
2) Here you're using "JsonDeserializer" not "JsonCreator", in the "deserialize" method does  "JsonParser" and "DeserializationContext"  need to initialize somewhere with config (like ignoreCamelCase or something)? If so, where should I initialize and inject them?
3) Is it possible to extract the "module" into a separate class?

Comment: 1) Only every time you create a new ObjectMapper, which should be only once. 2) the config is inherited by the ObjectMapper that is created, however the ignore camel case and most other are referring to the property name (enum values are not property names). You could add more values to the map of the Deserializer if you want to have more than one String match to a enum 3) Yes, just create the YourModule which extends the SimpleModule and add the deserializers in the constructor

Comment: Is there anyway that I can re-use the map or method defined in `ValueEnumDeserializer ` from my Enum? For example, if I need to a converter method `fromValue` that will receive an integer value and return me the mapped Enum, e.g RoleType.fromValue(1) will return Admin, how could I better use the generic concept within ValueEnumDeserializer? 
Or do I have to declared the method in the `ValueEnum` interface? If so then I'll have to implement it by creating a duplicate map in my Enum while in ValueEnumDeserializer I already had a map used for deserialization

Comment: You cannot add such method in the interface because it's a static method. In any case you would need a new map with integer keys instead of strings. However given the number of enum members you could easily loop through all and check their value using the `values()` array.